# WCF How can I set clientCredentialType on custom binding

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security

I'm using the excellent [DuplexHttpBinding](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/duplexhttp). I now want to extend it so that I can use transport security with message credentials. I have some normal `BasicHttpBinding`s set up in this mode like so:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Custom">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

However I can't do the same thing with my `DuplexHttpBinding` because it doesn't have security element.

My question is: how can I set up my `DuplexHttpBinding` with `TransportWithMessageCredential`? Or. more generally, how do you set up the message security on a binding you've created by inheriting from `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding`?

I've been struggling to find any info about this, so any links to relevant docs would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add a `SecurityBindingElement` as the first element in the `BindingElementCollection`, so in the `CreateBindingElements` method of your binding:

```
SecurityBindingElement security = SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();
collection.Add(security);
```